# How to get the inputText field value by document.getElementById in adf?

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

I want to get the value of an `inputText` field through `document.getElementById` in a `javascript` method in adf. Below is my javascript method. But instead of a specific value i got `"undefined"` in the alert. How can i get the specific value of an inputText field by `document.getElementById` in adf ?

```
    function refresh() {
        try {
            var val = document.getElementById('pt1:flag');
            alert(val.value);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: pt1:flag explain what is this? is it " id" of textbox

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2280168?tstart=0

Comment: pt1 is the id of template
<af:pageTemplate viewId="/template/SampleTemplate.jspx" id="pt1">

and flag is the id of text field
<af:inputText label="fdsfsd" value="5" id="flag"/>

Comment: Try it without the `pt1:` => `var val = document.getElementById('flag');`

Comment: If i do not use pt1: it shows "TypeError" in the alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by the following code,

```
var val = document.getElementById('pt1:flag::content');
```

Comment: Mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the code snippet,

```
 var val = document.getElementById('pt1').value;
 alert(val);
```

Comment: this is exactly what he is doing now

Comment: he isn't doing a .value